# slow results from ubuntu redis while things work fast from a windows machine - same code

Tags: c#, redis, stackexchange.redis

so i have this client that's using StackExchange.Redis with C#. he is using a windows redis server and i created an ubuntu redis server for him.

the problem is that when he's querying the windows redis, with the same code he's getting the results pretty much instantly while it takes 10-20 seconds to get the results from the linux box. both boxes have identical hardware and i have the linux box performance optimized.

here's a couple screenshots with the relevant code and the queries:

https://www.screencast.com/t/D2puFlh3j
https://www.screencast.com/t/5WxAcqCZGt

if anyone would give me a few ideas on how to get the things working properly, i would appreciate it.

thank you.

Comment: Is the data set the same for both? You really shouldn't be using KEYS like that, see https://redis.io/commands/keys

Comment: yeah the data is the same. i took a dump from the windows box and loaded it on the ubuntu one. i didn't do the code. what bugs me is that on the linux server, the redis behaves like that(slow) and on the windows box aparently it works fine.